# Export a Python List to Excel

Tags: python

```
score_sheet = [[2],[1],[0],[0],[6],[0],[0],[1],[0],[2],[1],[1],[4],[0],      [0],[0, 'W', 'S Dhawan c \xe2\x80\xa0Uthappa b Morkel 6 '],[1],[0],[4],[0, 'W', 'DA Warner c SA Yadav b UT Yadav 13 '],[0],[2],[0],[1],[1],[0],[0],[1],[2],[0],[4],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0, 'W', 'MC Henriques lbw b UT Yadav 6 '],[0],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[0],[0],[0],[1],[0],[1],[0],[1],[1],[0],[2],[1],[1],[0],[0, 'W', 'DJ Hooda c UT Yadav b Russell 6 '],[2],[0],[1],[1],[0],[0],[1],[0],[2],[2],[0],[4],[0],[0],[1],[0],[1],[4],[4],[0],[4],[0],[3],[2],[0],[4],[0],[1],[1],[6],[0],[0],[1],[1],[1],[0],[6],[2],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1],[6],[1],[1],[0, 'W', 'NV Ojha c Chawla b Morkel 37 '],[1],[1],[6],[1],[1],[1],[0, 'W', 'EJG Morgan c Shakib Al Hasan b UT Yadav 51 '],[1],[6],[1],[1],[1],[2],[1, 'W', 'A Ashish Reddy run out 13 '],[1]]

import xlwt
from tempfile import TemporaryFile  
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('sheet1')
for i,e in enumerate(score_sheet):
    if len(score_sheet[i])==1:
        sheet1.write(i,1,e[0])
    else:
        sheet1.write(i,1,e[0])
        sheet1.write(i,2,e[1])
        sheet1.write(i,3,e[2])
n = "score_book.xls"
book.save(n)
book.save(TemporaryFile())
```

I want to convert score_sheet into excel file 
And it is showing these errors:

File "", line 2, in 
    book.save(name)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 710, in save
    doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 674, in get_biff_data
    shared_str_table   = self.__sst_rec()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 636, in __sst_rec
    return self.__sst.get_biff_record()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 77, in get_biff_record
    self._add_to_sst(s)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 92, in _add_to_sst
    u_str = upack2(s, self.encoding)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\UnicodeUtils.py", line 50, in upack2
    us = unicode(s, encoding)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Can you please guide me what should I do?

Comment: You are passing Unicode text from str object. What is you file encoding?

Answer (score 3):

You're using non-Unicode strings in a function that wants Unicode strings. Python 2 will attempt to do the conversion automatically, but it uses the `'ascii'` codec which doesn't handle all the characters.

Replace:

```
'S Dhawan c \xe2\x80\xa0Uthappa b Morkel 6 '
```

with:

```
u'S Dhawan c \u2020Uthappa b Morkel 6 '
```